# Storing Unity3d string with white spaces into VARCHAR field in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine, varchar, spaces

I'm working on something with Unity3d MySQL Db. I am passing values through `$_GET` PHP method but I'm having trouble with strings with white spaces when I store them into the assigned tables.

Let's say I have an InputField which gets the string I need. Then, I pass the string through the `$_GET` method, like this:

```
public InputField myInput;
public string a;

void StoreData()
{
     a = myInput.text;
     StartCoroutine(store(a));
}

IEnumerator store(string str)
{
     WWW connection = new WWW("http://localhost/route/store_company.php?name=" + str);
     yield return(connection);
}
```

So, after connecting to the DB, in the php file I have:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$query = "INSERT INTO company(id, name) VALUES (NULL, '$name')";
$get_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
echo '101';
```

If I type *"Example"* in the InputField, the VARCHAR column called name will have "Example". But if I type *"This is an example",* the VARCHAR column just stores the first word ("This") missing the rest of the sentence.

I've sat the VARCHAR to 70 (Length). Pretty new using MySQL. ¿How I capture the whole sentence and why don't work if I am passing a string variable?

Comment: `name` is a MySQL keyword, so you either need to changethe column name or back tick it when using in queries.

Comment: For query strings you need to use `htmlentities()` on the value before trying to store.Furthermore you should learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: I have them in spanish and don't work.

Comment: Have what in Spanish and what doesn't work?

Comment: You know that spaces are not allowed in URL query strings, right?

Comment: Replace the spaces with urlencoded string, str = WWW.EscapeURL(str);  This defaults to UTF8 encoding which can be overriden with the second parameter. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.EscapeURL.html

Comment: @Jay The name of the columns and tables are in spanish. I had forgotten about the spaces in URL. But I need to pass the whole string somehow.

Comment: Then you have to modify the URL to have the %20 space character.

Comment: @JayBlanchard How I do that or where can I learn how? Also, I tried what Landern said and it works in some fields and don't work in others.

Comment: @Landern That solved the problem. Imma check about how to override the enconding.